# How to loop objects and run an expensive method using multi-threading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a list of locations. (Location)

then inside the loop I want to save all these locations into a local db

the `saveLocation()` function is very expensive, so I need to save all locations at the same time (multi-threading)

```
// save all locations using multithreading
for (Location location : dataFromServer) {
    // add location into local db
    // TODO: create thread
    DataBaseHelper.getInstance(activity).saveLocation(location);
}

// TODO: join threads
```

## Edit

This is the Database helper class

```
public class DataBaseHelper {

    private static DataBaseHelper instance;
    private static DaoMaster daoMaster;

    private DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(context, "DatabaseName", null);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
    }

   synchronized public static DataBaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
       DataBaseHelper localInstance = instance;
       if (localInstance == null) {
           synchronized (DataBaseHelper.class) {
               localInstance = instance;
               if (localInstance == null) {
                   instance = localInstance =new DataBaseHelper(context);
               }
           }
       }
       return localInstance;
    }

    public long saveLocation(Location location) {
        Log.e("id",location.getId());
        DaoSession daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
        ...
        if (locationFromDao == null) {
            return daoSession.getLocationDao().insert(location);
        } else {
            daoSession.getLocationDao().update(location);
            return Long.valueOf(location.getId());
        }
    }

...

}
```

Comment: You probably *can’t*. Even if *your* code does the saving in parallel, the database will have to synchronise and serialise access. You should figure out why saving the location is so expensive, and fix that — a simple write into a database shouldn’t be that inefficient, or if it is (device latency …), the database should allow you to write multiple records in a single operation.

Comment: Would be helpful to see what `DataBaseHelper.getInstance(activity)` and `(dbInstance)..saveLocation(location)` actually do. And whether there would be a chance to add a new `saveLocations(dataFromServer)` method to do the operation with one single DB access like @KonradRudolph suggested.

Comment: `DataBaseHelper.getInstance()` probably establishes a *new database connection* every time, which is a very heavy operation. ***Don't do that.*** Get a single connection, then use **batching** to save multiple records. --- If `saveLocation()` needs to do `INSERT` or `UPDATE` depending on whether records already exists, use an `UPSERT` statement (or whatever it's called in the database you're using).

Comment: hey, thanks. I updated the question and added some more code:
how can I use a single connection?

Comment: Why do you want to save the locations one by one if you start off with a collection of them, which usually should be way more effient to save?

Comment: how can I save a collection of Location with one connection?